# Create vpn server in pythonanywhare

Tags: vpn, pythonanywhere

i want to create a vpn in python is it possible i heard something called pythonanywhare if anyone knows if it is possible to do with it please help everything is vpn in our country youtube pip github npm nothing is working and I want to be a software developer can you give me information

Comment: That would not work on PythonAnywhere as you run on a shared infrastructure.